# Prefixing all react links within the app

Tags: reactjs, react-router-redux

I have several links throughout my `react` app that look like this:

```
<Route path="/linkpath" component={Whatever} />
```

or

```
<Link to="/linkpath">Click Me</Link>
```

Is there a quick/easy way to prefix all the links throughout the app with a predetermined string? ... perhaps via a `Router` configuration param?

So for example if my prefix is "/foo", all links to "/linkpath" would be converted to `/foo/linkpath`.

*Note*: Just to clarify, I'm using `react-router-dom` v4.0.0-beta.5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the `Router` in `react-router-dom` v4.0.0-beta.5 has a param called [`basename`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/#basename-string) that addresses this scenario.

```
<Router basename="/foo">
  <Link to="/linkpath">Click Me</Link>
  <!-- other links here -->
</Router>
```

In this case, Click Me's link will be `/foo/linkpath`. So, as long as `Router` wraps all `Components` in the app, all links will be prefixed with `basename`.

*One important note*: Make sure the string in `basename` starts with a *slash*; i.e., use "`/foo`" instead of "`foo`". The latter one produces undesired behavior when clicking links (it appends the full link path to the existing URL everytime you click the link, instead of replacing it).

Answer (score -1):

Using **React Router**, if you defined your routes using nesting like this:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/" component={App}>
    <Route path="/hello" component={Hello} />
    <Route path="/whatever" component={Whatever} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

Then you can simply change the path of the **outermost Route** component and it will add the prefix. In the case above, you could change it to:

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Route path="/api" component={App}>
    <Route path="/hello" component={Hello} />
    <Route path="/whatever" component={Whatever} />
  </Route>
</Router>
```

And then all the nested routes will be at `/api/hello`, `/api/whatever` instead of the original `/hello` and `/whatever`.

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work for me. I should have mentioned that I'm using `react-router-dom` v4.0.0-beta.5. I think things have changed a bit there.